# Custom report on unrelated object

Tags: custom-report-type

I need to create a custom report tying Contact with Account and Relationship.

Contact - Child of Account 
Relationship - Child of Contact 
No relationship between Account and Relationship

I tried joined report but I am getting no fields in common error. Can anyone suggest me how we could achieve this.

Comment: What do you expect your report to look like? It should be possible to create a "Contacts and Relationships" report that also includes Account details via lookup.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for your response that will meet the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce reports permit you to descend one-to-many relationships only along one "branch" of a tree. However, you can add fields to your Custom Report Type that are reachable via a lookup relationship, allowing you to go back "up" the tree.

Here, it appears that you can achieve your objective by creating a Custom Report Type for "Contacts and Relationships" (Contact is primary object, Relationship secondary). You can then use the "Add fields related via lookup" link to draw in fields from the Accounts related to those Contacts.